# Exception connecting to KNX IP Router - Invalid argument

Tags: java, knx

I am using the Calimero library to try and connect to my KNX system. The stack trace that keeps coming up is this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'knxNetworkLink' defined in class path resource [io/symphony/knx/config/KnxConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink]: Factory method 'knxNetworkLink' threw exception; nested exception is tuwien.auto.calimero.KNXException: connecting 127.0.1.1:41243 10.0.1.223:3671 (bound)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at io.symphony.knx.Application.main(Application.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink]: Factory method 'knxNetworkLink' threw exception; nested exception is tuwien.auto.calimero.KNXException: connecting 127.0.1.1:41243 10.0.1.223:3671 (bound)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: tuwien.auto.calimero.KNXException: connecting 127.0.1.1:41243 10.0.1.223:3671 (bound)
    at tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.ClientConnection.connect(ClientConnection.java:134) ~[calimero-core-2.5-M1.jar:na]
    at tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.KNXnetIPTunnel.<init>(KNXnetIPTunnel.java:193) ~[calimero-core-2.5-M1.jar:na]
    at tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.KNXnetIPTunnel.newTcpTunnel(KNXnetIPTunnel.java:139) ~[calimero-core-2.5-M1.jar:na]
    at tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLinkIP.newTunnelingLink(KNXNetworkLinkIP.java:158) ~[calimero-core-2.5-M1.jar:na]
    at io.symphony.knx.config.KnxConfig.knxNetworkLink(KnxConfig.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.symphony.knx.config.KnxConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e2e5d48.CGLIB$knxNetworkLink$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.symphony.knx.config.KnxConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e2e5d48$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9c2d5c1c.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at io.symphony.knx.config.KnxConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e2e5d48.knxNetworkLink(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:574) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:563) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648) ~[na:na]
    at tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.Connection.connect(Connection.java:719) ~[calimero-core-2.5-M1.jar:na]
    at tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.ClientConnection.connect(ClientConnection.java:129) ~[calimero-core-2.5-M1.jar:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Something is an "invalid argument" but I don't understand what might be the problem. The code below is what I use: It's based on Springboot and I configure the connection via the application.yaml. Those values (only one in this case) get mapped into the `KnxProperties` object which I use further down to set up the KNXNetworkLinx bean.

**application.yaml**

```
knx:
  connection:
    remoteAddress: 10.0.1.223
```

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "knx")
@Getter @Setter
public class KnxProperties {

    private Connection connection;

    @Configuration
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class Connection {

        private String remoteAddress;
        
        private Integer remotePort = 3671;
        
        private String localAddress = null;
        
        private Integer localPort = 0;
        
    }
    
}
```

```
    
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import tuwien.auto.calimero.IndividualAddress;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.KNXException;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.Connection;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXLinkClosedException;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLinkIP;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.link.medium.KNXMediumSettings;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.process.ProcessCommunicator;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.process.ProcessCommunicatorImpl;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.process.ProcessListener;

@Configuration
public class KnxConfig {

    @Bean
    public KNXNetworkLink knxNetworkLink(KnxProperties config) throws KNXException, InterruptedException, UnknownHostException {
        // Remote Socket
        String remoteAddr = config.getConnection().getRemoteAddress();
        InetAddress remoteInetAddr = InetAddress.getByName(remoteAddr);
        int remotePort = config.getConnection().getRemotePort();
        InetSocketAddress remote = new InetSocketAddress(remoteInetAddr, remotePort);
        
        // Local Socket
        int localPort = config.getConnection().getLocalPort();
        InetSocketAddress local = new InetSocketAddress(localPort);
        if (config.getConnection().getLocalAddress() != null) {
            local = new InetSocketAddress(config.getConnection().getLocalAddress(), localPort);
        }
        
        // Setup connection to KNX
        Connection conn = Connection.newTcpConnection(local, remote);
        KNXMediumSettings settings = KNXMediumSettings.create(KNXMediumSettings.MEDIUM_TP1, new IndividualAddress("1.1.1"));
        KNXNetworkLink link = KNXNetworkLinkIP.newTunnelingLink(conn, settings);
    
        return link;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProcessCommunicator processCommunicator(KNXNetworkLink link, Set<ProcessListener> listeners) throws KNXLinkClosedException {
        ProcessCommunicator comm = new ProcessCommunicatorImpl(link);
        listeners.forEach(l -> comm.addProcessListener(l));
        return comm;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your KNX IP Interface supports TCP?

Comment: At this point, I am not sure of anything :D How could I verify?

Comment: I could verify a tcp connection can be opened via `telnet 10.0.1.223 3671`. So I think that would prove it, right?